# Storing a set of strings to be accessed via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a tiny demo of an interactive fiction game.  Here's a page where I'm playing with styling, which should show you how it's intended to work: http://victoriabrockmeier.com/querent/format.html .  You get some text, you have links, sometimes in the text and sometimes as a list after the text; you click your selected action, and you get more text.  Etc.  There will be a total of about 6 scenes, with the right side clearing between scenes.

I'm already using jQuery to style the scrollbars, so it looks like .append() should be the most straightforward way to add text.  My incredibly basic question is, what do people consider the best way to store data like that to then load into a page, and what do I need to do to then access that data?  I know I could conceivably put everything in a bunch of arrays of strings in the page itself, but that seems messy.

(Also, I know building a substantial game in JavaScript and jQuery is not what one would do; for the moment, I just want to get the first intro bit up so I can show people where it's headed.)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your strings in an external javascript file which I think would be fine:

```
<script src="/path/to/strings.js"></script>
```

or you could put it in a JSON file and load it with `$.getJSON()` if you want to do it dynamically.